# How can I merge and sort two sorted lists of QTreeWidgetItems?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QTreeWidget with a bunch of QTreeWidgetItems. Each QTreeWidgetItem has a timestamp that is in the form of a QDateTime. The QTreeWidget is sorted by timestamp. I have another list of QTreeWidgetItems that is also sorted by timestamp. I want to add this list of QTreeWidgetItems to my QTreeWidget and end up with combine sorted list of QTreeWIdgetItems in a QTreeWidget.

Currently, this is how I am combining the two lists of QTreeWidgetItems:

```
    #1
    #self is my QTreeWidget class
    numItems = self.topLevelItemCount()
    #items is the new list of QTreeWIdgetItems to be added
    numAddItems = len(items)

    if numAddItems == 0:
        return

    while addItemIndex < numAddItems:
        addItem = items[addItemIndex]

        if itemIndex < numItems:
            item = self.topLevelItem(itemIndex)
            addItemDateTime = items[addItemIndex].getTimestamp()
            itemDateTime = item.getTimestamp()
            if addItemDateTime < itemDateTime:
                self.insertTopLevelItem(itemIndex, addItem)
                addItemIndex += 1
        else:
            self.addTopLevelItem(addItem)
            addItemIndex += 1
        itemIndex += 1
        numItems = self.topLevelItemCount()
```

I know that to merge and sort two Python lists, I can do something like this:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 3, 4, 7]  
>>> l2 = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]  
>>> sorted(l1 + l2)  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I know QTreeWidget has a sortItems() method. How would I tell QTreeWidget to use the QDateTime to sort?

I could also do something like this:

```
#2
#self is a QTreeWidget
#get a list of all the QTreeWidgetItems in the QTreeWidget
currentItems = []
numItems = self.topLevelItemCount()
for i in range(numItems):
    currentItems.append(self.topLevelItem(i))
#clear the QTreeWidget
self.clear()
#perform a merge sort on the list of all the QTreeWidgetItems
items = self.mergesort(currentItems + newItems)
for item in items:
    self.addTopLevelItem(item)
```

So what's a better way to combine my two lists of QTreeWidgetItems?

Comment: I haven't checked, but `sorted(l1 + l2, key=lambda x: x.getTimestamp())` feels right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did this in my Python code:

```
sortedItems = sorted(currentItems, key=lambda x: x.getTimestamp())
```

However, I had to rewrite the app in C++, and this is what I did in C++:

```
void TreeWidget::sortTreeWidgetItems(QVector<LogEvent *> currentItems) {
    qSort(currentItems.begin(), currentItems.end(), compareLogEventsByTimestampDesc);
}

bool compareLogEventsByTimestampDesc(LogEvent *eventA, LogEvent *eventB) {
    QDateTime aTimestamp = eventA->getTimestamp();
    QDateTime bTimestamp = eventB->getTimestamp();
    return (aTimestamp > bTimestamp);
}
```

Where `LogEvent` inherits `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a `QTreeView` with a [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstandarditemmodel.html), this would be easy.

The timestamps could be added with [`QStandardItem.setData`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstandarditem.html#setData) (using a custom role), and then the sort key could be set on the model using [`QStandardItemModel.setSortRole`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstandarditemmodel.html#sortRole-prop).